# What are the meaning or differences in this Rendition of El

Tags: genesis, names-of-god, god

In the Hebrew
ĕ·lō·hîm - God
ĕ·lō·hāy - gods
ĕ·lō·he·ḵā - gods
ĕ·lō·hê - gods

Elohe

Gen 31:32 BIB+ עִ֠ם ‘im  with  אֲשֶׁ֨ר ’ă·šer  anyone here ,  תִּמְצָ֣א tim·ṣā  If you find  אֶת־ ’eṯ-  -  אֱלֹהֶיךָ֮ ’ĕ·lō·he·ḵā  your gods  לֹ֣א lō  he shall not  יִֽחְיֶה֒ yiḥ·yeh  live !  נֶ֣גֶד ne·ḡeḏ  In the presence of  אַחֵ֧ינוּ ’a·ḥê·nū  our relatives ,  הַֽכֶּר־ hak·ker-  see  לְךָ֛ lə·ḵā  for yourself  מָ֥ה māh  if anything  עִמָּדִ֖י ‘im·mā·ḏî  is yours ,  וְקַֽח־ wə·qaḥ-  and take  לָ֑ךְ lāḵ  it back . ”  וְלֹֽא־ wə·lō-  did not  יָדַ֣ע yā·ḏa‘  know  יַעֲקֹ֔ב ya·‘ă·qōḇ  For Jacob  כִּ֥י kî  that  רָחֵ֖ל rā·ḥêl  Rachel  גְּנָבָֽתַם׃ gə·nā·ḇā·ṯam  had stolen [the idols].

Elohay

Gen 31:30 BIB+ וְעַתָּה֙ wə·‘at·tāh  Now  הָלֹ֣ךְ hā·lōḵ  you have gone off  הָלַ֔כְתָּ hā·laḵ·tā  . . .  כִּֽי־ kî-  because  נִכְסֹ֥ף niḵ·sōp̄  you long  נִכְסַ֖פְתָּה niḵ·sap̄·tāh  . . .  לְבֵ֣ית lə·ḇêṯ  house .  אָבִ֑יךָ ’ā·ḇî·ḵā  for your father’s  לָ֥מָּה lām·māh  But why  גָנַ֖בְתָּ ḡā·naḇ·tā  have you stolen  אֶת־ ’eṯ-  -  אֱלֹהָֽי׃ ’ĕ·lō·hāy  my gods ? ”

Eloheka

Gen 31:32 BIB+ עִ֠ם ‘im  with  אֲשֶׁ֨ר ’ă·šer  anyone here ,  תִּמְצָ֣א tim·ṣā  If you find  אֶת־ ’eṯ-  -  אֱלֹהֶיךָ֮ ’ĕ·lō·he·ḵā  your gods  לֹ֣א lō  he shall not  יִֽחְיֶה֒ yiḥ·yeh  live !  נֶ֣גֶד ne·ḡeḏ  In the presence of  אַחֵ֧ינוּ ’a·ḥê·nū  our relatives ,  הַֽכֶּר־ hak·ker-  see  לְךָ֛ lə·ḵā  for yourself  מָ֥ה māh  if anything  עִמָּדִ֖י ‘im·mā·ḏî  is yours ,  וְקַֽח־ wə·qaḥ-  and take  לָ֑ךְ lāḵ  it back . ”  וְלֹֽא־ wə·lō-  did not  יָדַ֣ע yā·ḏa‘  know  יַעֲקֹ֔ב ya·‘ă·qōḇ  For Jacob  כִּ֥י kî  that  רָחֵ֖ל rā·ḥêl  Rachel  גְּנָבָֽתַם׃ gə·nā·ḇā·ṯam  had stolen [the idols].

Elohim

Gen 2:2 BIB+ וַיְכַ֤ל way·ḵal  had finished  אֱלֹהִים֙ ’ĕ·lō·hîm  God  בַּיּ֣וֹם bay·yō·wm  day  הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י haš·šə·ḇî·‘î  And by the seventh  מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ mə·laḵ·tōw  the work  אֲשֶׁ֣ר ’ă·šer  -  עָשָׂ֑ה ‘ā·śāh  He had been doing ;  וַיִּשְׁבֹּת֙ way·yiš·bōṯ  He rested  בַּיּ֣וֹם bay·yō·wm  day  הַשְּׁבִיעִ֔י haš·šə·ḇî·‘î  so on [that]  מִכָּל־ mik·kāl  from all  מְלַאכְתּ֖וֹ mə·laḵ·tōw  His work  אֲשֶׁ֥ר ’ă·šer  . . .  עָשָֽׂה׃ ‘ā·śāh  . . . .

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see two distinct uses in Gen 31:32, only one.  So I will treat this verse, which has only a single instance of "El..." as one instance.

before answer this question we should recall that Hebrew is a semitic language and thus is constructed very differently from Indo-European languages (eg, Germanic/English, Greek, Slavic, Romance, etc).  Hebrew nouns have numerous features such as conjunctions and some pronouns built into them.  In Indo-European languages, these features are usually separate words.

**Gen 31:32**

The operative word here is אֱלֹהֶיךָ֮ (eloheka) which is "your gods" being a noun masculine plural construct ("gods"), second person masculine singular ("your"), referring the idols that Rachel had stolen.

**Gen 31:30**

The operative word here is אֱלֹהָֽי׃ (elohay) which is "my gods" being masculine singular construct ("gods"), first person common singular ("my"), again referring the idols that Rachel had stolen

**Gen 2:2**

The operative word here is אֱלֹהִים֙ (Elohim) which is "God" being masculine plural (with no attached "bits" such as conjunctions ete).  The word is plural in form but the associated verb, וַיְכַ֤ל (waykal = "and ended") is singular.  Thus, the noun must be translated as singular.

All the above nouns are various forms of exactly the same noun, אֱלֹהִים֙ (Elohim).

Answer (score 0):

**Some Hebrew Background**

In Hebrew, pronouns often become suffixed to the verb, noun, or adjective with which they are associated.  This changes the form of the word.  In terms of verbs, because Hebrew does not have "tenses" (past, present, future) as does English, scholars prefer to term the various patterns of Hebrew verbs as "shapes."  Shapes change based on the modality (mood) of the verb, whether or not it is prefixed by a conjunction, and whether or not it is suffixed by a pronoun. (Note that a Hebrew noun and verb may have identical spellings, just as often occurs in English, so context must always be considered.)

Hebrew verbs, nouns, and adjectives typically consist of three root letters.  These letters then form the basis of the various shapes of the words.  In the case of "elohim," the three root letters are:  aleph+lamed+heh, as read from left to right.  The aleph is not pronounced, but its vowel is pronounced--like the silent "h" in the English word "honor."  The final mem is added to indicate masculine plural.

Nouns in Hebrew have both gender and number, usually discernible from their suffix.

**The Root is the Same**

The word "אָלָה" (Alah) uses the same Hebrew root letters as for אֱלֹהִ֑ים (Elohim).  Note that it is in *singular* form.

Here are some examples of various forms of this word root.

- אָלָה -- an oath (noun); to swear, curse (verb) (H423/H422)
- אֵלִי֙ -- my God (eli) (H430) (e.g. Exodus 15:2)
- אֱלֹהַי֙ -- my God (elohay) (H430) (e.g. Ezra 7:28) (construct state)
- אֱלֹהֵ֥י -- God of (elohay) (H430) (construct state, e.g. God of Israel, God of Abraham, God of their fathers)
- אֱלֹהִ֑ים -- God/gods (elohim) (H430)
- אֱלֹ֨הֵיכֶ֜ם -- your God/gods (elohekam) (H430)

Most of these forms differ only in their vowel pointings (Niqqud) or perhaps in their accentuation and cantillation marks (Te'amim).  None of these markings were part of the original text: they were added by the Masoretes from about AD 500 to AD 1100 -- even after the Bible was "canonized."

NOTE: Ezra 7:28 appears exceptional to me (Hebrew does have many exceptions), as the statement "my God" appears to come at *the end* of the construct noun chain (Yahweh my God), not at the beginning where construct state is usually found.  The last word in the chain should be in its normal form, called "absolute" state.  (I'm making a note to ask my Hebrew professor about this, and may come back with an update later.)

**Analysis**

Seeing that list of word "conjugations" might already answer this question.  Essentially, the word "elohim" is just one of the forms in which this noun can exist.  When one looks in an English dictionary, it is unlikely to have every word form indexed: the dictionary will have the base form, and include the variant forms with it, e.g. *asker, asked, asking,* etc. will all come under the entry for *ask*.  This is also true of Hebrew.  The root word is the same, and has the same meaning: only the grammatical context has changed.

It should also be noted that "elohim," although plural in form, will represent a singular entity in context when used with singular verbs or adjectives.  This is akin to "fish" or "sheep" in English--if one says "the fish *are*," the hearer understands that "fish" is plural, but if "the fish *is*," then one knows "fish" is singular.

**Conclusion**

The meanings of the various word forms of "elohim" shown in the question are the same; only the grammatical form and context differ among them.